# Is it possible to transfer an id value from view to controller?

Tags: codeigniter

What I want to do is get the id from a button on my view:

```
<button type="submit" id="stuff">
```

to my controller, so I can change the style with:

```
echo '<style type="text/css">
           #stuff{
        background-color: #11eb00;
        }
     </style>';
```

Is this possible in CodeIgniter, or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: you are doing it completely wrong

Comment: It looks like you're doing it completely wrong. If you want to add a style to the element, just put it in your CSS file. If you need to change the style according to some logic, just use a class that you can echo in your view when necessary.

Comment: Care to tell me what I should be doing then, Kai? :p
Ah, thanks Derek. I think I get what you're saying. Let me see if that works!

Comment: @DerekSchlesselman I'm stuck. Care to give me an example?

Comment: I am unsure what exactly you are trying to do... If you want to style the button, the answer below works. If you need to conditionally style something output a boolean from your controller and test for it in the view (something like <p class="<?php if(myBoolean){ echo 'class-name'; } ?>>...</p>, then style .class-name in your css)

Comment: We need more information. Take us through the whole desired process. It sounds like you want the style of `#stuff` to change when clicked? There are tons of ways to do this and what you are doing isn't one of them. But what you describe currently isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use PHP to output any css. This would be a general misuse of the intended system.

You can just put the css style as you defined it in the html, or ideally in its own css file that is properly linked in the header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path-to-your-stylesheet.css">
```